# Limits and deleted neighborhood

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x_0, \ell \in \mathbb R$. Assume that $f$ is defined on a deleted neighborhood of $x_0$ with $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = \ell$. Let $g$ be defined on a neighborhood of $\ell$.

Show that $g \circ f$ is defined on a deleted neighborhood of $x_0$.

I understand that if $f$ is defined on a deleted neighborhood of $x_0$, then it means that the domain of $f$ contains a deleted neighborhood of $x_0$.
I also understand that $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = \ell$ means that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < |x-x_0| < \delta$.

But if $g$ is defined on a deleted neighborhood of $\ell$. I can see that $g \circ f$ will be defined on a deleted neighborhood of $x_0$ but I am confused about how to prove it. Could anyone help me out please. Thank you.

Comment: What's $m$ for?

Comment: There's is no m. That was for another part of the question. Sorry.

Comment: Proving this statement probably requires identifying the deleted neighborhood on which $g\circ f$ is defined, in terms of the other things you've said. I'm guessing you believe the statement because two things that need to be true are: $f$ is defined near $x_0$ and takes values near $\ell$, and $g$ is defined near $\ell$. Can you guess how to turn this into an argument involving deleted neighborhoods? (PS: typically $f\circ g$ means apply $g$ first, then $f$; so I think you mean $g\circ f$ here.)

Comment: Yes it is $g \circ f$. Sorry for the typo. Well I understand that f(x) takes vales near the deleted neighborhood on which g is defined. But from there I am lost.

Comment: How do we prove that $g \circ f$ is defined on a deleted neighborhood of $x_0$ based on that facts that f is defined near $x_0$ and takes values near $\ell$ and g is defined near $\ell$? Thank you